# Get Email ID associated with TriggeredSendDefinition

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to retrieve the Email object associated with the TriggeredSendDefinition in Exact Target. For this, I am trying to find the location of Email (i.e. Folder ID of the associated Email) for the triggeredSend. I tried retrieving the Email object but it said 
"Error: The Request Property(s) Email do not match with the fields of TriggeredSendDefinition retrieve".  I am required to do this using code (API). Please help.

**EDIT**

```
I have tried the following 

String requestID;
String status;
APIObject[] results;
RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest{
    ObjectType = "TriggeredSendDefinition",
    Properties =  new string[] { "CustomerKey", "Email.Folder", "Email.Name" }
};
SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart{
        Property = "CustomerKey",
        SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals,
        Value = "expiry_notice"
};
rr.Filter = sfp;
soapClient.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out results);
foreach (TriggeredSendDefinition df in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(df.CustomerKey + " " + df.Email.Name+" " + df.Email.Folder);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any sample code of what you did try?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.folder` and .`name` and just print out the email object?  I don't write in C# typically, so trying to eliminate any obvious issues.  I'm thinking tying to call the objects in this way is causing you headaches.

Answer (score 1):

The call you are making is to retrieve an Email object, filtered on `CustomerKey` by the value `expiry_notice`.  In it you are passing `Properties =  new string[] { "CustomerKey", "Email" }` which isn't working. `Email` is not one of the listed properties on the [email object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27962/get-email-id-associated-with-triggeredsenddefinition). Also, when you specify properties, you only get those listed in the return.

Delete the line `Properties =  new string[] { "CustomerKey", "Email" }` and it should return the folder information you are looking for.

Comment: I had mistake in the code I typed here. The ObjectType is supposed to be TriggeredSendDefinition. It has Email object defined inside.

Comment: In a similar fashion - remove the properties, and see if you can get to it from there. I think it's the properties line that is causing you to not be able to get to the objects properly.